# How to enable c++14 in gdal 2.4 with gcc 5.5

Tags: c++, gcc, build, c++14, gdal

I need gdal with BigTiff and c++14. The first one is fine. But I have some problem with c++14 even if I have gcc 5.5 (which should be fine if I refer to this https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx14)

What I did :

Install gcc like this :

```
wget http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-5.5.0/gcc-5.5.0.tar.gz
tar xvf gcc-5.5.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-5.5.0

./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++

make -j8
make -j8 install
```

Then install gdal 2.4 like this :

```
wget https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/archive/v2.4.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf v2.4.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-2.4.1/gdal

./configure
make -j6
make install
```

What I get from configure step :

```
GDAL is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Installation directory:    /usr/local
  C compiler:                gcc -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
  C++ compiler:              g++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
  C++14 support:             no

  LIBTOOL support:           yes

  LIBZ support:              external
  LIBLZMA support:           no
  ZSTD support:              no
  cryptopp support:          no
  crypto/openssl support:    no
  GRASS support:             no
  CFITSIO support:           no
  PCRaster support:          internal
  LIBPNG support:            external
  DDS support:               no
  GTA support:               no
  LIBTIFF support:           external (BigTIFF=yes)
  LIBGEOTIFF support:        external
  LIBJPEG support:           internal
  ...
```

So BigTiff is fine... but I don't have c++14. It may come from the line `C++ compiler: g++ -std=c++11` but I don't know how to change that. By the way I'm on CentOs 7.

Does anyone know what I should do to enable c++14 with gdal ?

Comment: what `./configure --help` prints? There should instruction how to enable `C++14`.

Comment: Try `./comfigure --with-cpp14` based on [that](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/gdal/master/gdal/configure).

Answer (score 0):

Here the help of configure :

```
./configure --help
`configure' configures this package to adapt to many kinds of systems.

Usage: ./configure [OPTION]... [VAR=VALUE]...

To assign environment variables (e.g., CC, CFLAGS...), specify them as
VAR=VALUE.  See below for descriptions of some of the useful variables.

Defaults for the options are specified in brackets.

Configuration:
  -h, --help              display this help and exit
      --help=short        display options specific to this package
      --help=recursive    display the short help of all the included packages
  -V, --version           display version information and exit
  -q, --quiet, --silent   do not print `checking ...' messages
      --cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
  -C, --config-cache      alias for `--cache-file=config.cache'
  -n, --no-create         do not create output files
      --srcdir=DIR        find the sources in DIR [configure dir or `..']

Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
  --exec-prefix=EPREFIX   install architecture-dependent files in EPREFIX
                          [PREFIX]

By default, `make install' will install all the files in
`/usr/local/bin', `/usr/local/lib' etc.  You can specify
an installation prefix other than `/usr/local' using `--prefix',
for instance `--prefix=$HOME'.

For better control, use the options below.

Fine tuning of the installation directories:
  --bindir=DIR            user executables [EPREFIX/bin]
  --sbindir=DIR           system admin executables [EPREFIX/sbin]
  --libexecdir=DIR        program executables [EPREFIX/libexec]
  --sysconfdir=DIR        read-only single-machine data [PREFIX/etc]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR    modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
  --localstatedir=DIR     modifiable single-machine data [PREFIX/var]
  --runstatedir=DIR       modifiable per-process data [LOCALSTATEDIR/run]
  --libdir=DIR            object code libraries [EPREFIX/lib]
  --includedir=DIR        C header files [PREFIX/include]
  --oldincludedir=DIR     C header files for non-gcc [/usr/include]
  --datarootdir=DIR       read-only arch.-independent data root [PREFIX/share]
  --datadir=DIR           read-only architecture-independent data [DATAROOTDIR]
  --infodir=DIR           info documentation [DATAROOTDIR/info]
  --localedir=DIR         locale-dependent data [DATAROOTDIR/locale]
  --mandir=DIR            man documentation [DATAROOTDIR/man]
  --docdir=DIR            documentation root [DATAROOTDIR/doc/PACKAGE]
  --htmldir=DIR           html documentation [DOCDIR]
  --dvidir=DIR            dvi documentation [DOCDIR]
  --pdfdir=DIR            pdf documentation [DOCDIR]
  --psdir=DIR             ps documentation [DOCDIR]

System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]

Optional Features:
  --disable-option-checking  ignore unrecognized --enable/--with options
  --disable-FEATURE       do not include FEATURE (same as --enable-FEATURE=no)
  --enable-FEATURE[=ARG]  include FEATURE [ARG=yes]
  --enable-shared[=PKGS]  build shared libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-static[=PKGS]  build static libraries [default=yes]
  --enable-fast-install[=PKGS]
                          optimize for fast installation [default=yes]
  --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking (might break parallel builds)
  --enable-debug          enable debugging (disabled by default)
  --enable-lto            enable LTO(link time optimization) (disabled by
                          default)
  --disable-rpath         do not hardcode runtime library paths
  --enable-pdf-plugin     enable PDF driver as a plugin (included in libgdal
                          by default)

Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --with-cpp14            Enable C++14 compiler options
  --with-pic[=PKGS]       try to use only PIC/non-PIC objects [default=use
                          both]
  --with-aix-soname=aix|svr4|both
                          shared library versioning (aka "SONAME") variant to
                          provide on AIX, [default=aix].
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld [default=no]
  --with-sysroot[=DIR]    Search for dependent libraries within DIR (or the
                          compiler's sysroot if not specified).
  --without-libtool     Don't use libtool to build the library
  --without-ld-shared   Disable shared library support
  --with-unix-stdio-64=ARG Utilize 64 stdio api (yes/no)
  --with-sse=ARG        Detect SSE availability for some optimized routines (ARG=yes(default), no)
  --with-ssse3=ARG        Detect SSSE3 availability for some optimized routines (ARG=yes(default), no)
  --with-avx=ARG        Detect AVX availability for some optimized routines (ARG=yes(default), no)
  --with-hide-internal-symbols=ARG Try to hide internal symbols (ARG=yes/no)
  --with-rename-internal-libtiff-symbols=ARG Prefix internal libtiff symbols with gdal_ (ARG=yes/no)
  --with-rename-internal-libgeotiff-symbols=ARG Prefix internal libgeotiff symbols with gdal_ (ARG=yes/no)
  --with-rename-internal-shapelib-symbols=ARG Prefix internal shapelib symbols with gdal_ (ARG=yes/no)
  --with-local=dir      Include /usr/local or other local tree for INCLUDE/LIBS
  --with-threads=ARG    Include thread safe support (ARG=yes(default), no or linkopt)
  --with-libz=ARG       Include libz support (ARG=internal or libz directory)
  --with-gnu-ld           assume the C compiler uses GNU ld default=no
  --with-libiconv-prefix[=DIR]  search for libiconv in DIR/include and DIR/lib
  --without-libiconv-prefix     don't search for libiconv in includedir and libdir
  --with-liblzma=ARG       Include liblzma support (ARG=yes/no)
  --with-zstd=ARG       Include zstd support (ARG=yes/no/installation_prefix)
  --with-pg=ARG           Include PostgreSQL GDAL/OGR Support (ARG=path to
                          pg_config)
  --with-grass=ARG      Include GRASS support (GRASS 5.7+, ARG=GRASS install tree dir)
  --with-libgrass=ARG   Include GRASS support based on libgrass (GRASS 5.0+)
  --with-cfitsio=ARG    Include FITS support (ARG=no or libcfitsio path)
  --with-pcraster=ARG   Include PCRaster (libcsf) support (ARG=internal, no or path)
  --with-png=ARG        Include PNG support (ARG=internal, no or path)
  --with-dds=ARG        Include DDS support (ARG=no, or path)
  --with-gta=ARG        Include GTA support (ARG=no or libgta tree prefix)
  --with-pcidsk=ARG     Path to external PCIDSK SDK or internal (default)
  --with-libtiff=ARG    Libtiff library to use (ARG=internal, yes or path)
  --with-geotiff=ARG    Libgeotiff library to use (ARG=internal, yes or path)
  --with-jpeg=ARG       Include JPEG support (ARG=internal, no or path)
  --with-charls           Include JPEG-Lossless support
  --without-jpeg12        Disable JPEG 8/12bit TIFF support
  --with-gif=ARG        Include GIF support (ARG=internal, no or path)
  --with-ogdi=ARG       Include OGDI support (ARG=path)
  --with-fme=ARG        Include FMEObjects support (ARG=FME_HOME path)
  --with-sosi=ARG        Include SOSI support (ARG=SOSI lib Path, yes or no)
  --with-mongocxx=ARG        Include MongoCXX support (ARG=Path, yes or no)
  --with-boost-lib-path=ARG   Path to boost libraries for mongocxx client
  --with-hdf4=ARG       Include HDF4 support (ARG=path)
  --with-hdf5=ARG       Include HDF5 support (ARG=path)
  --with-kea=ARG      Include kealib (ARG=path to kea-config) [default=yes]
  --with-netcdf=ARG     Include netCDF support (ARG=no or netCDF tree prefix)
  --with-jasper=ARG     Include JPEG-2000 support via JasPer library (ARG=path)
  --with-openjpeg     Include JPEG-2000 support via OpenJPEG 2.x library
  --with-fgdb=ARG        Include ESRI File Geodatabase support (ARG=FGDP API Path, yes or no)
  --with-ecw=ARG        Include ECW support (ARG=ECW SDK Path, yes or no)
  --with-kakadu=ARG     Include Kakadu/JPEG2000 support
  --with-mrsid=ARG      Include MrSID support (ARG=path to MrSID DSDK or no)
  --with-jp2mrsid=ARG   Enable MrSID JPEG2000 support (ARG=yes/no)
  --with-mrsid_lidar=ARG      Include MrSID/MG4 LiDAR support (ARG=path to LizardTech LiDAR SDK or no)
  --with-j2lura=ARG    Include JP2Lua support (ARG=no, lura SDK install path)
  --with-msg=ARG          Enable MSG driver (ARG=yes or no)
  --without-bsb           Disable BSB driver (legal issues pending
  --with-oci=[ARG]        use Oracle OCI API from given Oracle home
                          (ARG=path); use existing ORACLE_HOME (ARG=yes);
                          disable Oracle OCI support (ARG=no)
  --with-oci-include=[DIR]
                          use Oracle OCI API headers from given path
  --with-oci-lib=[DIR]    use Oracle OCI API libraries from given path
  --without-grib          Disable GRIB driver
  --with-gnm            Build GNM into shared library
  --with-mysql=ARG      Include MySQL (ARG=path to mysql_config) [default=no]
  --with-ingres=ARG     Include Ingres (ARG=$II_SYSTEM)
  --with-xerces=[ARG]     use Xerces C++ Parser from given prefix (ARG=path);
                          check standard prefixes (ARG=yes); disable (ARG=no)
  --with-xerces-inc=[DIR] path to Xerces C++ Parser headers
  --with-xerces-lib=[ARG] link options for Xerces C++ Parser libraries
  --with-expat=[ARG]      use Expat XML Parser from given prefix (ARG=path);
                          check standard prefixes (ARG=yes); disable (ARG=no)
  --with-expat-inc=[DIR]  path to Expat XML Parser headers
  --with-expat-lib=[ARG]  link options for Expat XML Parser libraries
  --with-libkml=[ARG]     use Google libkml from given prefix (ARG=path);
                          check standard prefixes (ARG=yes); disable (ARG=no)
  --with-libkml-inc=[DIR] path to Google libkml headers
  --with-libkml-lib=[ARG] link options for Google libkml libraries
  --with-odbc=ARG       Include ODBC support (ARG=no or path)
  --with-dods-root=ARG  Include DODS support (ARG=no or absolute path)
  --with-curl=ARG       Include curl (ARG=path to curl-config.)
  --with-xml2=ARG       Include libxml2 (ARG=path to xml2-config.)
  --with-spatialite=ARG Include SpatiaLite support (ARG=no(default), yes, dlopen (only supported for Spatialite >= 4.1.2) or path)
  --with-spatialite-soname=ARG Spatialite shared object name (e.g. libspatialite.so), only used if --with-spatiliate=dlopen
  --with-sqlite3=[ARG]    use SQLite 3 library [default=yes], optionally
                          specify the prefix for sqlite3 library
  --with-rasterlite2=ARG Include RasterLite2 support (ARG=no(default), yes or path)
  --with-pcre             Include libpcre support (REGEXP support for SQLite)
  --with-teigha=path Include Teigha DWG/DGN support
  --with-teigha-plt=platform Teigha platform
  --with-idb=DIR        Include Informix DataBlade support (DIR points to Informix root)
  --with-sde=DIR        Include ESRI SDE support (DIR is SDE's install dir).
  --with-sde-version=VERSION NUMBER  Set ESRI SDE version number (Default is 80).
  --with-epsilon=ARG    Include EPSILON support (ARG=no, yes or libepsilon install root path)
  --with-webp=ARG    Include WEBP support (ARG=no, yes or libwebp install root path)
  --with-geos=ARG         Include GEOS support (ARG=yes, no or geos-config
                          path)
  --with-sfcgal=ARG       Include SFCGAL support (ARG=yes, no or sfcgal-config
                          path)
  --with-qhull=ARG     Include QHull support (ARG=no, yes, internal)
  --with-opencl=ARG       Include OpenCL (GPU) support
  --with-opencl-include=ARG OpenCL Include directory (with a CL subdirectory)
  --with-opencl-lib=ARG   OpenCL Link Flags (i.e. -L/xxx -lOpenCL)
  --with-freexl=ARG    Include freexl support (ARG=no, yes (default) or libfreexl install path)
  --with-libjson-c=ARG       Include libjson-c support (ARG=internal or libjson-c directory)
  --without-pam         Disable PAM (.aux.xml) support
  --with-poppler=ARG    Include poppler(for PDF) support (ARG=no(default), yes or poppler install path)
  --with-podofo=ARG    Include podofo(for PDF) support (ARG=no(default), yes or podofo install path)
  --with-podofo-lib=ARG   podofo Link Flags (i.e. -L/xxx -lpodofo ...). Mainly for static libpodofo
  --with-podofo-extra-lib-for-test=ARG   Additional libraries to pass the detection test, but not used for libgdal linking (i.e. -ljpeg ...). Mainly for static libpodofo
  --with-pdfium=ARG    Include pdfium (for PDF) support (ARG=no(default), yes or pdfium install path)
  --with-pdfium-lib=ARG   pdfium Link Flags (i.e. -L/xxx -lpdfium ...). Mainly for static libpdfium
  --with-pdfium-extra-lib-for-test=ARG   Additional libraries to pass the detection test, but not used for libgdal linking (i.e. -ljpeg ...). Mainly for static libpdfium
  --with-proj=ARG Compile with PROJ.x (ARG=no or path)
  --with-proj5-api=ARG Allow using PROJ.5 new API  (ARG=no/yes, default to yes)
  --with-static-proj4=ARG Compile with PROJ.4 statically (deprecated, use --with-proj instead) (ARG=no or path)
  --with-gdal-ver=ARG   Override GDAL version
  --with-macosx-framework         Build and install GDAL as a Mac OS X Framework
  --with-perl           Enable perl bindings
  --with-python=ARG   Enable python bindings (ARG=yes, no, or path to python binary)
  --with-java       Include Java support (ARG=yes, no or JDK home path)  [default=no]
  --with-hdfs=ARG        Include HDFS support (ARG=Path or no)
  --with-mdb       Include MDB driver
  --with-jvm-lib=ARG        ARG is dlopen or points to Java libjvm path
  --with-jvm-lib-add-rpath    Add the libjvm path to the RPATH (no by default)
  --with-rasdaman=DIR        Include rasdaman support (DIR is rasdaman's install dir).
  --with-armadillo=ARG       Include Armadillo support for faster TPS transform computation (ARG=yes/no/path to armadillo install root) [default=no]
  --with-cryptopp=ARG       Include cryptopp support (ARG=yes, no or path)
  --with-crypto=ARG       Include crypto (from openssl) support (ARG=yes, no or path)
  --without-mrf           Disable MRF driver
  --without-lerc          Disable LERC library
  --with-null             Enable NULL driver (only useful for development
                          purposes

Some influential environment variables:
  CC          C compiler command
  CFLAGS      C compiler flags
  LDFLAGS     linker flags, e.g. -L<lib dir> if you have libraries in a
              nonstandard directory <lib dir>
  LIBS        libraries to pass to the linker, e.g. -l<library>
  CPPFLAGS    (Objective) C/C++ preprocessor flags, e.g. -I<include dir> if
              you have headers in a nonstandard directory <include dir>
  CXX         C++ compiler command
  CXXFLAGS    C++ compiler flags
  LT_SYS_LIBRARY_PATH
              User-defined run-time library search path.
  CPP         C preprocessor
  CXXCPP      C++ preprocessor
  PKG_CONFIG  path to pkg-config utility
  OGDI_CFLAGS C compiler flags for OGDI, overriding pkg-config
  OGDI_LIBS   linker flags for OGDI, overriding pkg-config
  HDF5_CFLAGS C compiler flags for HDF5, overriding pkg-config
  HDF5_LIBS   linker flags for HDF5, overriding pkg-config
  OPENJPEG_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for OPENJPEG, overriding pkg-config
  OPENJPEG_LIBS
              linker flags for OPENJPEG, overriding pkg-config
  LIBKML_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for LIBKML, overriding pkg-config
  LIBKML_LIBS linker flags for LIBKML, overriding pkg-config
  POPPLER_CFLAGS
              C compiler flags for POPPLER, overriding pkg-config
  POPPLER_LIBS
              linker flags for POPPLER, overriding pkg-config

Use these variables to override the choices made by `configure' or to help
it to find libraries and programs with nonstandard names/locations.

Report bugs to the package provider.
```

So you were right, after doing this I got

```
C++ compiler:              g++ -std=c++14 -DHAVE_AVX_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSSE3_AT_COMPILE_TIME -DHAVE_SSE_AT_COMPILE_TIME -g -O2
C++14 support:             yes
```

I don't use to compile with ./configure, I didn't know it was possible to use --help...
Thanks gor your help !